# Can i download windows 7 on my laptop?

Tags: windows-7

Dell Inspiron B120

General

```
Recommended Use Small business
Width 14.0 in
Depth 10.5 in
Height 1.4 in
Weight 6.4 lbs
Color Black
Notebook type Mid-size laptops (6-7.5 lbs.)
Screen type Wide-screen
```

Processor

```
Processor Intel Celeron M 1.4 GHz
Data Bus Speed 400.0 MHz
```

Cache Memory

```
Type L2 cache
Installed Size 1.0 MB
```

RAM

```
Installed Size 256.0 MB
Technology DDR SDRAM
```

Storage

```
Floppy Drive None
Hard Drive 40.0 GB
Storage Removable None
Hard drive type Standard
```

Optical Storage

```
Type CD-RW / DVD-ROM
Read Speed 24x (CD) / 8x (DVD)
```

Display

```
Display Type 14.1 in TFT active matrix
Max Resolution 1280 x 800
```

Video

```
Graphics Processor / Vendor Intel GMA900
```

Audio

```
Audio Output Sound card
Audio Input Microphone
```

Input Device(s)

```
Input device type Touchpad,
Keyboard
```

Telecom

```
Modem Fax / modem
Max Transfer Rate 56.0 Kbps
Protocols & Specifications ITU V.92
```

Networking

```
Data Link Protocol Fast Ethernet,
Ethernet
```

Expansion / Connectivity

```
Expansion Slot(s) 2.0 Memory,
1.0
Interfaces 3.0 x Microphone - VGA,
1.0 x Display / video - RJ-45,
1.0 x Modem - Hi-Speed USB,
1.0 x Ethernet - RJ-11,
1.0 x Hi-Speed USB,
1.0
```

Power

```
Power Provided 60.0 Watt
```

Battery

```
Technology Lithium ion
Installed Qty 1.0
```

Operating System / Software

```
OS Provided Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition
Software Dell Media Experience,
Drivers & Utilities,
Corel WordPerfect
```

Comment: Even with XP, it probably runs very poorly with only 256MB of RAM. Try to get it up to 1GB. I usually consider 2GB the minimum for Windows 7 and Vista.

Comment: This is too localized - we can't go around telling everybody if Windows 7 will work on their exact configuration. Take a look at the [Windows 7 System Requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements) if you want to know if Windows 7 will work on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

No. You do not meet the RAM requirements.

Comment: is there a way to increase it?

Comment: what operating systems would work?

Comment: @jj38e I recommend just sticking to XP, its the last lightweight Windows operating system. If not, maybe its time to try Linux, starting with a Distro like Fedora < http://fedoraproject.org/ > which is very beginner friendly.

Comment: It might be possible to increase it, but at this point, its not worth it. You would need to update more than 2 parts to get a satisfactory experience. stick with XP or a linux distro,

Comment: According to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Inspiron%20B120&Cat=RAM), he can get up to 2GB but that doesn't look like the same laptop at all.  It doesn't look like the same type of RAM that a Celeron 1.4 GHz would support.  Not that I really know, however.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements to install Windows 7 are:

```
1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor

1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)

16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)

DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver
```

Your processor barely meets the requirement, you will likely find it to be very choppy and slow running Windows 7. Your also below the RAM requirement, as you only have 256mb. Your graphics card is probably fine, and hard drive is fine.

Based on my experience with Windows 7, I **HIGHLY** recommend not installing it on your machine. You will find it very slow and will struggle performance-wise. You may be able to upgrade your RAM, but your CPU will still be very sluggish with it. I have seen others try to do some on similar hardware, and ended up removing it quickly.

Note that,  although RAM is upgradable in a laptop, CPU is usually not, especially one this old.

Answer (score 1):

If you can increase your memory, that would help. [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/) has a scanner that will tell you what your computer can hold and offer possible configurations. Also verify if you system will have drivers support. If they don't offer any support or drivers for Windows 7 then it may be difficult to use all parts of the laptop, such as touchpad or wirelss.

Lastly, with the hardware you have I would suggest that you stick with Windows XP or try a Live CD of Linux ([Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/), etc....). Linux is just as easy to use these days, tons of help on the web, and it doesn't require the massive hardware requirements that Microsoft Windows needs. They also have greater hardware support for some older hardware.

Comment: This model only has drivers for DOS and XP.